# Is there a way to store the value of a variable in a table using INSERT in Myssql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench 8.0 and would like to store the value of a variable in a table using INSERT.

Let's say:

- I have a function defined as `func` which return a decimal.
- I have a stored procedure defined as `storedProcedure` which takes two parameters.

Inside the stored procedure, I would like to store the returned value of the function in a variable then insert all three values (two parameters + one returned result) in an existing table.

Here is what I unsuccessfully tried so far:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `storedProcedure`(
    IN param1 BOOL,
    IN param2 INTEGER(10)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE returnedValue DECIMAL(7,2);
    SET @returnedValue = (SELECT func());
    INSERT INTO existing_db.existing_table (
        column1,
        column2,
        column3
    )
    VALUES(
        @param1,
        @param2,
        @returnedValue
    );
END
```

When executing `call storedProcedure(param1Value, param2Value)` in a query tab, the console returns the

> error code 1048: column cannot be null.

PS:

1. During debugging, I noticed that the function works correctly and returns a value which is effectively store in the variable.
2. I also tried to access the value in variables using `(select @resultAG)` in the VALUES section of the INSERT statement.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: `DECLARE returnedValue` and `SET @returnedValue` are two **DIFFERENT VARIABLES**.

Comment: Of course, the same about `param1` and `@param1`, `param2` and `@param2`...

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `storedProcedure`(
    IN param1 BOOL,
    IN param2 INTEGER(10)
)
    INSERT INTO existing_db.existing_table (
        column1,
        column2,
        column3
    )
    VALUES(
        param1,
        param2,
        func()
    );
```

If you want not only save the value returned by the function into the table but use this returned value into the variable for future use in the connection code also then use

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `storedProcedure`(
    IN param1 BOOL,
    IN param2 INTEGER(10)
)
    INSERT INTO existing_db.existing_table (
        column1,
        column2,
        column3
    )
    SELECT
        param1,
        param2,
        @returnedValue := func()
;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=daaa2e7409dfc4e5e00675153134da9d